# bundle install gives me a lot of gems version errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundle

when I run bundle install I got this long error

```
bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rails-assets.org/...
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rails-assets.org/..
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
Resolving dependencies......................
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionmailer":
  In Gemfile:
    mail_form was resolved to 1.7.1, which depends on
      actionmailer (>= 3.2, < 6)

    rails (= 4.2.11.1) was resolved to 4.2.11.1, which depends on
      actionmailer (= 4.2.11.1)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionpack":
  In Gemfile:
    activeadmin was resolved to 1.4.3, which depends on
      formtastic (~> 3.1) was resolved to 3.1.5, which depends on
        actionpack (>= 3.2.13)

    activeadmin was resolved to 1.4.3, which depends on
      inherited_resources (>= 1.9.0) was resolved to 1.9.0, which depends on
        has_scope (~> 0.6) was resolved to 0.7.2, which depends on
          actionpack (>= 4.1)

    activeadmin was resolved to 1.4.3, which depends on
      inherited_resources (>= 1.9.0) was resolved to 1.9.0, which depends on
        actionpack (>= 4.2, < 5.3)

    rails (= 4.2.11.1) was resolved to 4.2.11.1, which depends on
      actionpack (= 4.2.11.1)

    activeadmin was resolved to 1.4.3, which depends on
      ransack (>= 1.8.7) was resolved to 1.8.10, which depends on
        actionpack (>= 3.0, < 5.2)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activemodel":
  In Gemfile:
    mail_form was resolved to 1.7.1, which depends on
      activemodel (>= 3.2, < 6)

    paperclip (~> 4.3.1) was resolved to 4.3.7, which depends on
      activemodel (>= 3.2.0)

    rails (= 4.2.11.1) was resolved to 4.2.11.1, which depends on
      activemodel (= 4.2.11.1)

    web-console (~> 2.0) was resolved to 2.3.0, which depends on
      activemodel (>= 4.0)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activerecord":
  In Gemfile:
    friendly_id (~> 5.4.0) was resolved to 5.4.2, which depends on
      activerecord (>= 4.0.0)

    rails (= 4.2.11.1) was resolved to 4.2.11.1, which depends on
      activerecord (= 4.2.11.1)

    rails-erd was resolved to 1.6.1, which depends on
      activerecord (>= 4.2)

    activeadmin was resolved to 1.4.3, which depends on
      ransack (>= 1.8.7) was resolved to 1.8.10, which depends on
        activerecord (>= 3.0, < 5.2)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activesupport":
  In Gemfile:
    activeadmin was resolved to 1.4.3, which depends on
      arbre (>= 1.1.1) was resolved to 1.4.0, which depends on
        activesupport (>= 3.0.0, < 6.2)

    jbuilder (~> 2.0) was resolved to 2.9.1, which depends on
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)

    activeadmin was resolved to 1.4.3, which depends on
      kaminari (>= 0.15) was resolved to 1.2.1, which depends on
        activesupport (>= 4.1.0)

    paperclip (~> 4.3.1) was resolved to 4.3.7, which depends on
      activesupport (>= 3.2.0)

    rails (= 4.2.11.1) was resolved to 4.2.11.1, which depends on
      activesupport (= 4.2.11.1)

    activeadmin was resolved to 1.4.3, which depends on
      ransack (>= 1.8.7) was resolved to 1.8.10, which depends on
        activesupport (>= 3.0, < 5.2)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "coffee-rails":
  In Gemfile:
    coffee-rails (~> 4.1.0)

    activeadmin was resolved to 1.4.3, which depends on
      coffee-rails

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "i18n":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 4.2.11.1) was resolved to 4.2.11.1, which depends on
      activesupport (= 4.2.11.1) was resolved to 4.2.11.1, which depends on
        i18n (~> 0.7)

    activeadmin was resolved to 1.4.3, which depends on
      ransack (>= 1.8.7) was resolved to 1.8.10, which depends on
        i18n

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "json":
  In Gemfile:
    recaptcha was resolved to 5.8.1, which depends on
      json

    sdoc (~> 0.4.0) was resolved to 0.4.2, which depends on
      json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "mimemagic":
  In Gemfile:
    paperclip (~> 4.3.1) was resolved to 4.3.7, which depends on
      mimemagic (= 0.3.0)

Could not find gem 'mimemagic (= 0.3.0)', which is required by gem 'paperclip
(~> 4.3.1)', in any of the sources.

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "paperclip":
  In Gemfile:
    paperclip (~> 4.3.1)

    paperclip-ffmpeg (~> 1.2.0) was resolved to 1.2.0, which depends on
      paperclip (>= 2.5.2)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rack":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 4.2.11.1) was resolved to 4.2.11.1, which depends on
      actionpack (= 4.2.11.1) was resolved to 4.2.11.1, which depends on
        rack (~> 1.6)

    omniauth-google-oauth2 was resolved to 1.0.0, which depends on
      oauth2 (~> 1.1) was resolved to 1.4.7, which depends on
        rack (>= 1.2, < 3)

    omniauth-google-oauth2 was resolved to 1.0.0, which depends on
      omniauth (~> 2.0) was resolved to 2.0.4, which depends on
        rack (>= 1.6.2, < 3)

    sass-rails (~> 5.0) was resolved to 5.0.7, which depends on
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0) was resolved to 3.7.2, which depends on
        rack (> 1, < 3)

    devise was resolved to 4.8.0, which depends on
      warden (~> 1.2.3) was resolved to 1.2.7, which depends on
        rack (>= 1.0)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 4.2.11.1)

    paperclip-ffmpeg (~> 1.2.0) was resolved to 1.2.0, which depends on
      rails

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "railties":
  In Gemfile:
    activeadmin was resolved to 1.4.3, which depends on
      railties (>= 4.2, < 5.3)

    coffee-rails (~> 4.1.0) was resolved to 4.1.1, which depends on
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.1.x)

    devise was resolved to 4.8.0, which depends on
      railties (>= 4.1.0)

    activeadmin was resolved to 1.4.3, which depends on
      jquery-rails (>= 4.2.0) was resolved to 4.4.0, which depends on
        railties (>= 4.2.0)

    rails (= 4.2.11.1) was resolved to 4.2.11.1, which depends on
      railties (= 4.2.11.1)

    sass-rails (~> 5.0) was resolved to 5.0.7, which depends on
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 6)

    web-console (~> 2.0) was resolved to 2.3.0, which depends on
      railties (>= 4.0)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "sprockets":
  In Gemfile:
    activeadmin was resolved to 1.4.3, which depends on
      sprockets (< 4.1)

    sass-rails (~> 5.0) was resolved to 5.0.7, which depends on
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "thor":
  In Gemfile:
    thor (= 0.19.1)

    activeadmin was resolved to 1.4.3, which depends on
      jquery-rails (>= 4.2.0) was resolved to 4.4.0, which depends on
        thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)

    rails (= 4.2.11.1) was resolved to 4.2.11.1, which depends on
      railties (= 4.2.11.1) was resolved to 4.2.11.1, which depends on
        thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
```

Here is my gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.11.1'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg', '~> 0.20.0'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development


group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end

gem 'devise'
group :development, :test do
  gem "interactive_editor"
  gem "hirb"
  gem "awesome_print"
  gem 'byebug'
end
group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor'
  gem 'puma'
end
gem 'mail_form'
gem 'font-awesome-sass', '~> 5.12.0'

gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~>3.2.0'

gem 'paperclip', '~> 4.3.1'

gem 'aws-sdk-s3'
gem 'aws-sdk', '< 2.0'

gem 'thor', '0.19.1'
gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2'
gem "recaptcha", require: "recaptcha/rails"
gem 'friendly_id', '~> 5.4.0'

gem 'activeadmin'
gem 'rails-assets-sweetalert2', source: 'https://rails-assets.org'
gem 'sweet-alert2-rails'
gem 'sweet-alert-confirm'
gem 'cocoon'
gem 'bigdecimal', '1.3.5'
gem 'paperclip-av-transcoder'
gem "paperclip-ffmpeg", "~> 1.2.0"
gem "will_paginate", "~> 3.0.4" 
gem 'rails-erd'
gem 'bundler', '1.17.3'
```

How can I fix it?
This error came after I changed the bundle version

Answer (score 0):

It is as the error message says. The versions you specify in the gem file is not available. This happens because each bundle version only supports down to a certain version, for example it can download any version from 2 and up but version 1 is not available. I see your gems are outdated, and you should consider to just update them. Unless you have done something version specific you should not need these restrictions anymore for rails version 4.2. If not you have to roll back your bundle version.

Answer (score 0):

The error is `mimemagic`, required by `paperclip`.

You'll have to upgrade or provide the `mimemagic` gem from source.
This happened to me and had to obtain the code from an old project in order to supply it.

For reference:
https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/41750